# How to put telephone plate back to the wall

Tags: drywall, kitchens, backsplash, telephone

I have this telephone plate in the kitchen and the backsplash tile is brand new.

[image]

I don't remember how it looks like before. There were only two wires coming out.

[image]

[image]

Now I don't want to cut the tile and insert a box. How to actually mount this back into the wall (now tile backsplash)? There is no way to screw in the plate. I am thinking about just superglue into tile somehow. Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: (It's upside down. That small cutout on the edge should be on the bottom edge.)

Comment: Will you have a phone hanging on the plate?

Comment: @isherwood You can't hang a phone off that one. It has two jacks and lacks the protruding locking screws for the phone to attach to

Comment: What's this *can't* you speak of? :)

Comment: @isherwood Fair enough. With a long enough stick you can move the world lol

Comment: That, and if it's ridiculous enough you can bet someone has done it. I like Gary's answer, but it's worth asking.

Comment: telephones !!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

I would just drill two holes into the tile and use plastic anchors to face mount it to the tiles.  Raise it  up slightly so the wires are in the recessed portion.

I wouldn't think super glue would work well here. Silicone may work but may end up looking messy.

Answer (score 1):

The cover plate you're showing is intended to be mounted on top of an inwall box, ie; single gang box nailed or screwed to a stud. As suggested, I'd get a masonry drill bit or tile bit of the appropriate size and use plastic molly anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Superglue should work just fine. It's a telephone socket so you're not going to be pulling stuff out forcefully ever.

Make sure to use just the right amount so that it doesn't drip but it's still all covered!

Comment: The problem with superglue is that if you **ever** need to get into the wiring or replace the jack (e.g., someone yanks a cable out and messes up the jack pins; you switch from one voice line to two and find out things aren't working quite right) then it will be a pain to deal with unless you remember it was superglue (and therefore use acetone to undo it).